# How to fix the ECONNREFUSED ERROR in a Dockerized NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I am trying to make a fetch request from a nodejs server ( that is dockerized --thus a container ) to a strapi server (that is also dockerized -- thus a container ).
I am running my containers using docker compose, meaning they already share the same network.
But i am getting the following error upon making a fetch request :

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] request to http://strapi:1377/api/login-page failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.7:1377
```

As you can see in the code below, I am using the service name of the container to make a request, but i can't seem to figure out what the error is:

Here's my code to fetch data :

```
export class GetLabelsService {
    async getRouteLabels(labelPath: string) {
        const request = `http://strapi:1377${labelPath}`;
        console.log(request)
        const res = await fetch(request);
        const labels_data = await res.json();
        return labels_data
    }
}
```

Here's my docker-yaml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-api
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: ${DB_TYPE}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      APP_HOST: ${APP_HOST}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      JWT_EXIPRY_TIME: ${JWT_EXIPRY_TIME}
      STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY: ${STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY}
      STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: ${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}
      currency: ${currency}
      FCM_DATABASE_URL: ${FCM_DATABASE_URL}
      SMTP_HOST: ${SMTP_HOST}
      SMTP_USERNAME: ${SMTP_USERNAME}
      SMTP_PASSWORD: ${SMTP_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_container
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      PMA_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 64M
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  strapi:
    build:
      context: ./cms
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-cms
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      APP_KEYS: ${APP_KEYS}
      API_TOKEN_SALT: ${API_TOKEN_SALT}
      ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: ${ADMIN_JWT_SECRET}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      MASTER_KEY: ${MASTER_KEY}
      MEILI_HOST: http://meilisearch:7700
      CLOUDINARY_KEY: ${CLOUDINARY_KEY}
      CLOUDINARY_NAME: ${CLOUDINARY_NAME}
      CLOUDINARY_SECRET: ${CLOUDINARY_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - ./cms/config:/srv/app/config
      - ./cms/src:/srv/app/src
      - ./cms/package.json:/srv/package.json
      - ./cms/yarn.lock:/srv/yarn.lock
      - ./cms/datadump:/srv/app/datadump
      - ./cms/public:/srv/app/public
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: yarn develop

  meilisearch:
    image: getmeili/meilisearch:latest
    environment:
      MEILI_MASTER_KEY: ${MASTER_KEY}
    ports:
      - 7700:7700
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv/app/data
      
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 8088:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  # Back-end services 
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  db_data:
  pgdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile-api

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:16-alpine

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/api
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/api/

RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start:dev" ]
```

My thoughts are maybe i am setting the wrong host name, but i can't seem to figure out the probblem. Any idea of what the cause of the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Your setting It seems to be OK. but your strapi port maybe different.

```
const request = `http://strapi:1377${labelPath}`;
```

and docker-compose.yml strapi has

```
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
```

so your connect code maybe

```
const request = `http://strapi:1337${labelPath}`;
```